# Java digital signature

Tags: java

I have this code to write data to file:

```java
public class Message {
    private List<byte[]> list;

    //The constructor of Message class builds the list that will be written to the file. The list consists of the message and the signature.
    public Message(String data, String keyFile) throws InvalidKeyException, Exception {
        list = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        list.add(data.getBytes());
        list.add(sign(data, keyFile));
    }

    //The method that signs the data using the private key that is stored in keyFile path
    public byte[] sign(String data, String keyFile) throws InvalidKeyException, Exception{
        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA"); 
        dsa.initSign(getPrivate(keyFile));
        dsa.update(data.getBytes());
        return dsa.sign();
    }

    //Method to retrieve the Private Key from a file
    public PrivateKey getPrivate(String filename) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }

    //Method to write the List of byte[] to a file
    private void writeToFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File f = new File(filename);
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
        out.writeObject(list);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Your file is ready.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException, Exception{

        String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type your message here");        
        new Message(data, "/home/user/Desktop/privateKey").writeToFile("/home/user/Desktop/test.txt");

    }
}
```

I want to replace the `writeToFile` method so it will be given only a path to a pre-made file with no input data from the `JOptionPane`, how can I do it?

Comment: *how can I do it?* **what have you tried?**

Comment: How does the title of your question relate to the body? I see nothing about digital signatures in the body of your question

Answer (score 0):

You should use the nio Files API, so the shortest version of the code will be

```
private void writeToFile(Path file, Object list) throws IOException {
    try(ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file,StandardOpenOption.APPEND))) {
        os.writeObject(list);
    }
}
```

By defining other OpenOptions in the `newOutputStream` method, you could control whether to create a new file (CREATE) or append to an existing (APPEND), overwrite an existing file TRUNCATE_EXISTING), or create only if not existing (CREATE_NEW) or some others.

To get a `Path` for a string filename simply use

```
Path pathToFile = Paths.get(stringFilename);
```